# Flux slider - picture cutting off at the bottom

Tags: jquery, image, slider, flux

I use Flux slider in my Wordpress and the problem Im getting is pretty weird - after I click away from the index page where the slider is - and then come back to the index and the slider - there's a cut-off in the bottom of the slider, about 10 pixels high.

I don't know what causes it, the only way to fix it is Ctrl+F5 but then it appears again after I return to the index page.

anybody know what could cause this problem?

Comment: The answer is sunspots until you post a link, sample code, or a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you haven't waited for the image to fully load before calling the slider. As lucuma mentioned, it's hard to say without an example.